# Refactoring Vue.js v2 to Vue.js 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How can I refactor my Vue2 components to Vue3? It's not clear from the docs.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <main class="flex-1">
            <h1>{{ main_text }}</h1>
            <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        if (!this.user_id) {
            return this.$router.push("/login");
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.setMainText('Welcome')
    },
    props: ["user_id"],
    data() {
        return {
            main_text: 'Hello World',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        setMainText(text) {
            this.main_text = text;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by refactor? The syntax above is valid in both versions

Comment: The mounted action isn't triggered

Comment: try out to remove the `return` keyword